# API testing using Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to do some API testing in Jmeter. I was trying to follow this https://octoperf.com/blog/2018/04/23/jmeter-rest-api-testing/ . But I need to get token from cookie.

Can anyone suggest me a solution? Using Jmeter version 5.0

Sorry, if this question was asked previously. But, I could't find a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally APIs don't use cookies so my expectation is that you need to extract [HTTP Header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) value instead

1. Take a look at `Response Data -> Response Headers` mode of the [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener and locate the value you need to extract.

   [image]
2. Add [Regular Expression Extractor](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter) as a child of the request and use the relevant regular expression in order to extract the interesting value. For example:

   - In order to extract `gws` from `Server: gws` header the regular expression would be `Server: (.*)`
   - In order to extract `1P_JAR` cookie value the regular expression would be `1P_JAR=(.+?);`
   - Don't forget to change Regular Expression Extractor's "Field to check" to `Response Headers`

   [image]

More information:

- [JMeter: Regular Expressions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Perl5 Regex Cheat Sheet](https://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet)

Answer (score 0):

Add the next line to user.properties file (located in the "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

CookieManager.save.cookies=true
Restart JMeter to pick the property up
Add HTTP Cookie Manager to your Test Plan
Now you should be able to refer cookie values as:

${COOKIE_session} and
${COOKIE__xsrf}  CHk More info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45520455/how-can-i-extraxt-session-id-and-xsrf-token-through-cookies-in-jmeter